# How to disable the Cordova webview in the background? (iOS only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm working on a iOS Cordova app that gets launched in the background to handle location events. This is working fine, but I've noticed that when the app gets launched in the background, the webview is initialized and my entire app is rendered. I have all the logic for handling the background launch written natively so I could (hopefully) avoid rendering the UI and running the Javascript side.

I thought I could disable the webview by wrapping the `MainViewController` creation in an `if` statement, but that doesn't seem to be working (I know the webview is being run because it's sending HTTP requests).

Here is my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "AppName-Swift.h"

@implementation AppDelegate {
  LocationSyncManager* locationSyncManager;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    bool isLocationLaunch = launchOptions[@"location"] == nil ? false : launchOptions[@"location"];
    NSString* serverAddress = @"http://192.168.1.61:9090/api/notes/nearby";
    locationSyncManager = [LocationSyncManager create: serverAddress isLocationLaunch: isLocationLaunch];

    // Don't render the webview if the app is launched in the background by a location event
    if(!isLocationLaunch) {
      self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issues:

`isLocationLaunch` was always `false` because I was checking the location launch flag wrong.

Also in order to keep Cordova from rendering/running javascript, I had to keep `super didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from being called during location launched.

This works:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "AppName-Swift.h"

@implementation AppDelegate {
  LocationSyncManager* locationSyncManager;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

    bool isLocationLaunch = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];

    NSString* serverAddress = @"http://192.168.1.61:9090/api/notes/nearby";
    locationSyncManager = [LocationSyncManager create: serverAddress isLocationLaunch: isLocationLaunch];

    if(!isLocationLaunch) {
      self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
      return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```